# Pass Generic Object Dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core, http-get, generic-list

I am trying to dynamically show a table depending on what tableName user has selected from dropdown. I am passing a json object from my web Controller(.Net Core) so in order to do it, I am first converting my dataTable to list of objects using function

```
public static List<T> ConvertTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
        {
            try
            {
                List<T> list = new List<T>();
            foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
            {
                T obj = new T();

                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }

                list.Add(obj);
            }

            return list;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and call this function in my Get Request

```
    public IActionResult GetTableDetailsByTableName(string TableNameSelected)
    {
        //To get the data for the Table Selected
        DataTable TableDetails = ReferenceTableLogics.getTableDetails(TableNameSelected);

        var TableDetailsInList = ConverterClass.ConvertTableToList<CSBM_AGE_BAND>(TableDetails);
        return Ok(TableDetailsInList);
    }
```

Now the issue is that I need to tell my class Name (eg `CSBM_AGE_BAND` in this case) depending on what user has selected in dropdown (`TableNameSelected`).

**Is there any way by which I can dynamically pass this class name to my function `ConvertTableToList` ?**

Comment: use reflection, see my answer bellow

Comment: Can you vote and/or comment if my answer was util for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection you can invoke your generic extension method:

```
Type genericType = Type.GetType("YourNamespace.ConverterClass");
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ConverterClass).GetMethod("ConvertTableToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod(genericType);
var TableDetailsInList = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[]{ TableDetails });
```